# Connection Errors on Initializing Spotify on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, spotify

I have been struggling with implementing the Spotify iOS SDK in a simple music player app I’m working on with the intention of learning more about the streaming platform’s API. My app’s features are storyboard-based and have simple functionality (i.e. connect/disconnect, pause/play, fast forward/rewind, fetch album artwork)

I modeled my authorization method off of the demo project SPTLoginSampleAppSwift, and have been trying to troubleshoot the errors I’m getting (I’ll paste them below).

After a few weeks of struggling with this API, I decided to run the demo project on my device and realized that it does not seem to function properly either. Does anyone know how I can fix these errors and successfully initiate Spotify functionality in my app? I’m quite frustrated and would really appreciate any advice. I'm including my repo below as well.

https://github.com/dglaser2/SpotifyPlayer

ERRORS:

Upon clicking connect:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify:" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

Upon returning to app after authorization screen:

```
2021-01-07 16:59:16.775788-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3692500] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-01-07 16:59:16.907970-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3688560] AppRemote: Connecting...
2021-01-07 16:59:16.921229-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3692500] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-01-07 16:59:16.923633-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3692500] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-01-07 16:59:16.926122-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3691493] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C2] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-07 16:59:16.926941-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3691493] TCP Conn 0x600002b6c0b0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2021-01-07 16:59:16.928526-0500 SpotifyPlayerDavid[39554:3688560] AppRemote: Failed connection attempt with error: Error Domain=com.spotify.app-remote.transport Code=-2000 "Stream error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stream error., NSUnderlyingError=0x600001228f00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Reconnect the transport to the Spotify app., NSLocalizedFailureReason=A stream error has occured in the transport.
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/39 ?

Comment: @SergeiSirik Thanks for your comment. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I'm including my github repo in my post now. Would greatly appreciate if you or anyone could take a look!